# Using "find" remove .js files and maintain .min.js files

Tags: shell, find

Having this folder (its a minified example):

```
js/
- folder/
    test.js
    test.min.js
    - inner folder/
        nice.js
        nice.min.js
- another_folder/
    hello.js
    hello.min.js
config.js
config.min.js
```

I want to get rid of the .js files (and maintain the min.js files). This would be my desired output:

```
js/
- folder/
    test.min.js
    - inner folder/
        nice.min.js
- another_folder/
    hello.min.js
config.min.js
```

How can I archieve this using `find`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
find . -iname '*.js' ! -iname '*.min.js'
```

Output

```
./js/another_folder/hello.js
./js/folder/inner folder/nice.js
./js/folder/test.js
./config.js
```

And to remove these files you just pipe them to `rm`

```
find . -iname '*.js' ! -iname '*.min.js' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: @MarkRoberts I don't think it matters for this case. But ya, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the blue, untested:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.min.js" |
  while read path
  do
    other="${path%.min.js}.js"
    rm -v "$other"
  done
```

Comment: This would remove only those x.js which do have a corresponding x.min.js. While this is true for the concrete example in the question, the OP asked that he wants to remove ** all** x.js, except of the x.min.js. Your approach would miss a blabla.js, when there is no blabla.min.js.

Comment: It was intentional to miss un-minified JS files. But yes, I see that the OP didn't explicitly ask for that.